# How do I edit files in the console when connecting to windows 7 via ssh?

Tags: windows, vim, ssh-tunnel

I am using tunnelier client and server to connect to a windows machine. I can get in and have access to all of the files on the computer. I have vim installed on that windows machine, but I can't seem to edit anything via the DOS command line. I also tried editing in notepad, but nothing happens when I enter the command. I think this might be the part where DOS doesn't behave like bash.

Would I need to setup cygwin / openssh to accomplish this? (boo, tunnelier is so easy)

Thanks!

p.s. I know I could just use sftp and edit files that way, but it feels dirty.

Comment: did you tried command line editor for DOS prompt called `edit`? It actually will look similarily to mcedit on linux. try it

Comment: For one thing, I don't see how Notepad.exe could display on your local PC over an SSH connection. SSH can forward X11, but it's not Remote Desktop, unless Tuneler does something clever. Similarly, gvim.exe probably won't show up locally either. Have you tried running console-mode vim.exe instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use vim from `cmd.exe`, make sure that the directory of the vim executable is in you `$PATH`.

Also make sure you use the terminal version (vim, not gvim) unless Tunneler does the Remote Desktop thing.